# Windows 10 Update Stuck at XX% - Any Fixes?"

Tags: windows-update

"I'm encountering an issue with my Windows 10 update where it gets stuck at XX% and doesn't progress further. I've tried restarting my computer, running the Windows Update Troubleshooter, and even resetting Windows Update components, but nothing seems to work. Does anyone have any suggestions or fixes for this problem? I'd appreciate any help!"

Comment: Could you check the Windows logs in the event Viewer, especially the "Setup" part and looking for error events

Comment: What updates are being installed? Do some install successfully? What percentage are they stopping at, or do they stop at different percentages each time? Checking the Event Viewer is a good first step, like @S.Brottes suggests.

Answer (score 0):

I list below all the advice I know for fixing Windows Update:

- Run the Windows Update troubleshooter in:
  *Settings > Update & Security > Troubleshoot > Additional troubleshooters >
  Windows Update > Run the troubleshooter*
- Run Microsoft's [Windows Update Troubleshooter for Windows 10](//support.microsoft.com/help/4027322)
- Reset Windows Update components by running these commands in an elevated
  Command Prompt:

  ```
  net stop wuauserv
  net stop cryptSvc
  net stop bits
  net stop msiserver
  Ren C:\Windows\SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old
  Ren C:\Windows\System32\catroot2 Catroot2.old
  net start msiserver
  net start wuauserv
  net start cryptSvc
  net start bits
  ```

  If all goes well, delete the `.old` folders (or return them if a problem
  arrives).
- Run the DISM tool in an elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /ScanHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /CheckHealth
  Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth
  ```
- Run the following in an elevated Command Prompt:

  ```
  SC config trustedinstaller start= auto
  ```
- If nothing fixes the problem, use a heavy gun:
  [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](//tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)

Comment: i tired resetting windows though i didn't find the solutions for my problem